# How do I encrypt a ConfigurationSection in ASP.NET Core 7.0?

Tags: c#, encryption, configuration, connection-string, configuration-files

I have a project with an *appsettings.Development.json* file, to which I've added the following section:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "Database one": "<Host...;Username=...;Password=...;etc.>"
}
```

When I search the internet for instructions on how to encrypt the *ConnectionStrings* section, I keep finding instructions that try to call functions that my IDE (VSCode) doesn't recognize (it doesn't even suggest that I must download a NuGet or import a *using*), which leads me to believe that it's all outdated, just as [this person](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59224941/18099006) did. But what confuses me is that even the Microsoft documentation (see [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-strings-and-configuration-files?source=recommendations#appconfig-example) and [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.sectioninformation.protectsection?view=windowsdesktop-7.0#examples)), which is supposed to be up to date, is instructing me to use the functions that VSCode doesn't recognize, such as *OpenExeConfiguration*, *SectionInformation*, *IsProtected*, and *ProtectSection*.

Below is my best attempt at creating working code from the examples I've found, but it doesn't work yet because VSCode is still unable to recognize *SectionInformation* and *ProtectSection*:

```
public void ProtectSection(ConfigurationManager cManager)
{
    try
    {
        var section = cManager.GetSection("ConnectionStrings") as ConfigurationSection;

        if (!section.SectionInformation.IsProtected)
        {
            section.ProtectSection("ConnectionStrings");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are using a method that is documented for ASP.NET applications - do you have an ASP.Net application? Also that documentation is about 8 or 9 years old - I don't think it is .NET 7

Comment: It's the only documentation I keep finding. I'm using ASP.NET Core 7.0. I created the project using the "ASP.NET Core with Angular" template that Visual Studio 2022 provides.

Comment: You may find this article worth reading for dealing with secrets in modern .NET (hint: skip encrypting appsettings.json): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=windows

Comment: That was what I needed. I'll accept it as the answer if you convert it to an answer and explain why the approach I was going for is inadvisable (and outdated?).